# Is a set containing rational numbers closed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

For the set $S$ $=$ $\{x^2: \sqrt 2 <x<\sqrt3\, ,\,x \in \Bbb R\}\,\cap$ $\Bbb Q$

Can I deduce that it is closed through this argument:

$S$ $=$ $[2,3]\,\cap$ $\Bbb Q$. Since $[2,3]$ is a closed set and $\Bbb Q$ is neither open nor closed implies that $S$ is closed as $S$ is an intersection of a closed set and a set which is not open. Thus, $S$ is a closed set.

However, I could have taken the first set as $(2,3)$ too and this argument wouldn't have worked. So is the set $S$ closed or neither open nor closed?

Comment: If you have a reference to a theorem that states that the intersection of a closed set and a non-open set is closed, then yes, you can make that deduction.

Comment: Closed as a subset of which space? $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: $[2,3]$ is closed and $[2.2,2.4)$ is neither open nor closed, but their intersection is not closed

Comment: @Angina Seng: in real numbers.

Comment: @Gae. S.: I don't know of a theorem as such

Comment: @Neowise The why do you use it in a proof? Are you trying to lie to the reader, or is it just a generic disregard for the thing you are doing?

Comment: @Gae. S. I don't know a proof for it, but to me it seems obvious. I know many things which are obvious but I don't have a proof for it. So I have only added it as an argument to verify the truth of it.

Comment: $S$ is not equal to $[2,3]\cap\Bbb Q$, because $2$ and $3$ are not elements of $\{x^2:\sqrt 2<x<\sqrt 3\}$.

Comment: I think it is closed in the space of $\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intersected $[2,3]$ with a set you knew was closed in $\mathbb R$, then you could deduce that the intersection was closed in $\mathbb R$, because there is a theorem saying that the intersection of two sets that are closed in $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.

However, you are intersecting $[2,3]$ with a set which is neither closed nor open in $\mathbb R$, namely $\mathbb Q$. And there is no theorem saying that a closed set in $\mathbb R$ intersected with a non-closed, non-open set in $\mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R$. The reason no such theorem exists is that it is false, one can easily provide counterexamples, such as $[2,3] \cap (2.5,3] = (2.5,3]$.

And, in fact, $[2,3] \cap \mathbb Q$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$, and neither is it open.